# Connecting an ESP8266 to AWS IoT Core - getting "WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Unknown error code."

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, esp8266

I am trying my first ever IoT project with an ESP8266 connecting to AWS IoT core.  I've checked all my certificates, setup etc and they appear to be correct.  However, when I run my code to publish a simple "Hello World" message to AWS IoT, I get:

Attempting MQTT connection...pm open,type:2 0
failed, rc=-4 try again in 5 seconds
WiFiClientSecure SSL error: Unknown error code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you need any more detail, I'd be happy to provide it.

Thanx,

ramesh.

Comment: Hi, we cannot help you without your code. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Tarmo - thanx for your help.  This is a tutorial I got off of YouTube.  Code here:  https://electronicsinnovation.com/how-to-connect-nodemcu-esp8266-with-aws-iot-core-using-arduino-ide-mqtt/#Source_Code_Program.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and what I ended up finding is that you have to set your certificates BEFORE you connect to the WiFi.

So try and make sure that you are setting those before calling `WiFi.begin(ssid, password)`